# database records missing randomly in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am using joomla as CMS I have a system of creating users from the back end and give those login information to the users to log in our site we are following this system as we only serve a selected group of people.
but I have noticed that some records were missing randomly in our database we are using phpmyadmin and database MySQL ,I have noticed the issue when some users complained that they couldn't login on our site with the credentials provided by us .When I checked the database table I found out that some records were missing randomly .I am totally puzzled and  helpless please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how anyone can help on the basis of that information. You have a "system of creating users", seems like that has some problems. What is the error handling like in that system, does it log every user it imports? What does it do if there's a problem? Can you rerun against some test database, see whether the same users fail to appear?

Comment: I am sorry for being not precise this I am a newbie actually this is the problem

Comment: Thanks for being sorry, but make good by providing more information. Can you duplicate the error? What have your tried? What are you seeing and when? What are your results; what were you expecting. Remember this is largely a community of developers. so provide information relevant to us.

Comment: I am sorry for being not precise this I am a newbie actually this is the problem.   1.I manually create a database record which consists of username and password, 2.then I give that user and password to users so that they can log in ,simply put there is no sign up feature but only sign in feature 3.but the problem is that the records that I am entering (username and password) are randomly disappearing from the database the order of disappearance is completely random the database is MySQL

Comment: Actually the problem is not being repeated in an order it is occurring randomly.

Comment: Please Edit your question to include relevant code and database schema.With this information we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Records do not under any normal circumstance disappear from databases spontaneously. Some specific actions must cause this.

First, carefully analyse your reasons for thinking the database ever had the record.

You have a process by which data is created. Suppose the code went:

```
 Generate username/password
 Print it out (and hence pass to user)
 Insert into database
```

and that last step failed, would you ever know? Can you run a quick query across the database when you believe the record should be there to check that it is?

If instead your code goes

```
 Generate username
 Insert into database
 Read from database
 Print it out
```

Then you have some evidence that the record did exist, now you need to track down when the deletion occurred. Somewhere there must be a delete running.

You need to get very analytic, gather evidence.